# Use grep in array

Tags: bash, shell

Below is the script to find specific array of different words "bots,spyware,virus" in file, if file exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

#strings to find in file
NAME[0]="bots"
NAME[1]="spyware"
NAME[2]="virus"

#location of file
LOGS=/home/testing.txt

#define function to grep any of the above mentioned array strings in file
func(){
if `grep "${NAME[*]}" $LOGS`; then
echo "CRITICAL: ${NAME[*]}"
else
echo "errors not found"
exit
fi
}

#file exist or not exist
if [ -f $LOGS ]; then
   echo " File Found"

  #call functions
  func
  modified

  else
   echo "File Not Found"
   exit
```

But `grep "${NAME[*]}" $LOGS` does not work. It shows below error:

```
grep: virus: No such file or directory
grep: bots: No such file or directory
```

Comment: learn to use `set -x` to turn on debugging trace of shell script (`set +x` to turn off). And you'll discover you need to convert your arr into a search target that looks like `grep 'a|b|c' file`. And great 2nd Q, but we only need to see the `func()` code, so learn to target your Qs to the non-working code. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution for the problematic part.

**Go to if-body when grep finds at least one entry of the array `KEYWORDS` in file `FILE`.**
The following code works for array entries with special characters like space  or `*`.

```
KEYWORDS[0]="virus"
KEYWORDS[1]="two words"
KEYWORDS[2]="special chars .+*?|()[]^&"

if grep -qF "${KEYWORDS[@]/#/-e}" -- "$FILE"; then
    # found a keyword
fi
```

What happens here?

- `grep -q`
  Do not output anything. Exit on the first match. We don't have to scan the complete file if we already found a keyword.
- `grep -F`
  Search fixed strings. Characters like `*`, `|`, or `+` lose their special meaning.
- `"{KEYWORDS[@]}"`
  Each entry of the array expands to one quoted string. Here `"virus" "two words" "special chars .+*?|()[]^&"`
- `"${KEYWORDS[@]/#/-e}"`
  Prepend `-e` to every entry of the array. Grep can search for multiple patterns using this option. `grep -e"FirstPattern" -e"SecondPattern" ...`
- `grep Pattern -- "$FILE"`
  The `--` is a hint, that `"$FILE"` should be interpreted as a file name. Its possible to name a file `-eFunny`, which would stop our script, because grep would think that no filename was provided and would wait for input from stdin. Its not really necessary here, but a good habit to establish. The so called *double dash* is available for most commands, not just grep.